# Varied column counts on mobile, tablet and desktop with Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

See https://jsfiddle.net/dszcm931/2/

**My markup (with Bootstrap 5)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col">5</div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col">6</div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col">7</div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col">8</div>
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block col">9</div>
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block col">10</div>
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block col">11</div>
        <div class="d-none d-xl-block col">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-cols-md-8">
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1 col-xl-2">Gutter Column</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-8">Content Column</div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-1 col-xl-2">Gutter Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I want:**
4 cols on `< md`, 8 cols on `>= md < xl`, 12 cols on `>= xl`

```
[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ]
[          content         ]

[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ][  5  ][  6  ][  7  ][  8  ]
[ gut ][                 content                ][ gut ]

[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ][  5  ][  6  ][  7  ][  8  ][  9  ][  10 ][  11 ]
[     gut    ][                     content                   ][     gut    ]
```

**What I'm getting:**
4 cols on `sm` 
12 cols on `xl` 
Some weird width totaling 7.25 cols on `md`

```
[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ]
[          content         ]

[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ][  5  ][  6  ][  7  ][  8  ]
[  gut  ][          content        ][  gut  ]

[  1  ][  2  ][  3  ][  4  ][  5  ][  6  ][  7  ][  8  ][  9  ][  10 ][  11 ]
[     gut    ][                     content                   ][     gut    ]
```

I have tried:

- Adding/removing `row-cols-md-8` to the rows (no effect)
- Removing `col-md-1` from the gutters (makes them full-width)
- Trying to always write my column widths in X/12. (Breaks all the things)

I can't figure out how to get MD right without breaking SM or XL

Comment: Agreed that the behavior in MD breakpoint is weird. On the other hand, if you just want to center the "content" column, you can apply `justify-content-center` CSS helper class at the `row`. The "gutter column" is unnecessary, unless you have contents to be put inside.

Comment: To "fix" your issue on MD breakpoint, you can set `col-md-2` on the gutter columns, `col-md-8` on content column to achieve your desired layout. (still counting 12 columns, although you have specified the class `row-cols-md-8` which means it will best render with 8 columns, according to the official docs). See [updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/p0jt2v4k/)

Comment: The problem with using a md width of anything other than 6 is sometimes the designs instruct us to split up content into 5 & 1, or 4 & 2, etc. So, if we change the md width to 8 or 10 or some other number to get it to look right, now the math for its content will be wrong.

Comment: PS: The other problem with the updated JSFiddle is that the gutters aren't 1/8th of the width.